# Understanding RxJs pipe and choosing the appropriate operator for it

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

I wrote this code and was promptly told this way of coding is 'not done' in Angular. They told me to research and use RxJs. I am however struggling to understand what I need for my use case. There are so many different options with the pipe operations that I am getting seriously confused about understanding which I need... So after reading through the [documentation](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-zip) I have come to stack overflow to hopefully get a clearer understanding of how the various pipes would work, and what I would need in my case...

I should note that I have only recently started doing Angular, while I understand the concepts of Observables, I am really struggling with setting up pipes, while they seem to be pretty integral in Angular...

First I am getting my data:

```js
getProjects(): Observable<ProjectsData> {
    return this.http.get('../../assets/projects.json') as Observable<ProjectsData>;
  }
```

and using it in this constructor to assign into my html:

```js
export class ProjectInfoComponent {
  project: IProject;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, dataReader: DataService) {
    dataReader.getProjects().subscribe(data => {
      route.data.subscribe(result => {
        data.projects.forEach(element => {
          if (element.route === result.id) {
            this.project = element;
          }
        });
      });
    });
  }
}
```

```js
export interface IProject {
    title: string;
    preview: string;
    header?: string;
    route?: string;
    alternatePreview?: string;
    softwareUsed?: string[];
    text?: string;
    thumbnailSize?: number;
}

export interface ProjectsData {
    projects: IProject[];
}
```

Link to actual JSON for reference: https://github.com/GrimZero/Portfolio/blob/master/docs/assets/projects.json

Comment: You question here is quite board really

Comment: While we understand that you are new to Angular, you have failed to explain what you are trying to achieve here..

Comment: @NicholasK I am loading data from a json file first, after that is done I need to check  the id that was passed into the router so I can get the right element out of the json file. this data is an interface which is used to apply variables to my html page.

Comment: 1. What does the json file / response look like? 2. Does your current attempt not work (sorry it isn't really clear)

Comment: @NicholasK The json file is an array of my IProject interface (that I have edited into my question). The response is working, but I am being told having a subscribe inside another subscribe is bad practice, so I am looking for the proper way to do this one.

Comment: TypeScript 2.9 allows you to import json files directly. You don't have to do a http request to get a json file from your assets folder. https://medium.com/@baerree/angular-7-import-json-14f8bba534af

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using RxJS 6, the right way would be to make use of pipeable operators. There are multiple ways of approaching this problem.

One way of doing so would have separate chains to handle the observables from both the service method and route, followed by using [combineLatest](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/combinelatest.html) to obtain the returned values.

```
const getProjects$ = dataReader.getProjects();
const getRoute$ = getProjects$.pipe(
  switchMap(user => route.data)
);

combineLatest(getProjects$, getRoute$).pipe(
  map(([data, result]) => {
    // handle the rest here
    data.projects.forEach(element => {
      if (element.route === result.id) {
        this.project = element;
      }
    });
  }),
).subscribe();
```

Comment: I am indeed using RxJS 6.4.0, this seems a lot cleaner to use than what I am doing.

Comment: Should I not save that subscription and unsubscribe in ondestroy though? or is that handled by the GC?

Comment: @TorbenVanAssche yes! You should still unsubscribe, and one way of doing so would be to use the  `takeUntil()` operator .

Answer (score 2):

You can use async pipe for that inside the template and avoid subscription inside the component.

In the component you would have:

```
private project$: Observable<IProject>;

...
this.project$ = this.dataReader.getProjects().pipe(map(projects => projects.find(project => project.id === id)))
```

Notice that you need to define id property, in your code you are comparing route object with id. Also consider to move that to ngOnInit instead of putting it into the constructor

In the template:

```
<div *ngIf="project$ | async as project">
    {{ project }}
</div>
```

Comment: My route is defined like this  { path: 'projectname', component: ProjectInfoComponent, data: {id: '0'} }, which I subscribe to when the active route changes

Answer (score 1):

In your ngOnInit() first get id of routed path.

```
ngOnInit(){
   const id  = this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
   this.service.getProjects(id).subscribe(data =>{ this.items = data })
}
```

then, In your service method is..

```
getProjects(id){
   return this.http.get('../../assets/projects.json').pipe(
      map(projects => projects.find(project => project.id === id))
   );
}
```